# PHP MySQL Count IF Google Charts and pull data from column / row

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Thank you in advance for your time.
I have two questions and I am very new at this.

What I am trying to accomplish is to pull data from an osticket database and then have google charts display a pie chart for me. I can get the code to pull the data, but it is pulling all the rows, which is fine for most columns, but for one column "isoverdue" I want it only to count it if, the row is = 1. I have tried a couple of different ways to add an if statement, but they always result in a failed MySQL error.

The second issue I am having is how can I get the google code to update dynamically? I have it hard coded with the results from the pull, but I am wondering how can I make, so that it is not hard coded? Perhaps I would need a new variable so it will total up the counts?

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = "";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(created) FROM ost_ticket') as $opened);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(closed) FROM ost_ticket') as $closed1);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(isoverdue) FROM ost_ticket') as $overdue);

echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>".$opened['COUNT(created)']."</td>", "<td>".$closed1['COUNT(closed)']."</td>", "<td>" .$overdue['COUNT(isoverdue)']."</td>";  
echo "</tr>";  

?>  


<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Status', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Opened',   8],
      ['Closed',   5],
      ['Overdue',  3],

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you again for taking your time to review this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `isoverdue`, try a `CASE` statement...

`SUM(CASE WHEN isoverdue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

also, you should be able to include them in the same statement,
so the query isn't run two extra times...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(created) as created,
  COUNT(closed) as closed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN isoverdue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as isoverdue
FROM
  ost_ticket
```

you can also name the fields with the `as` operator, then use the name to get value

```
foreach($dbh->query(...) as $results);
$results['created']
```

Comment: as for _update dynamically_, recommend having php build json object, which is called from ajax, then passed to a google charts [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1), similar to this [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)

Comment: If the closed column is  `NULL` until the ticket is actually closed, that will work. Since `COUNT(<column_name>)` will only count rows that are not null it will be different from `COUNT(created)` which is likely never `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

@WhiteHat,

Based off of your information, I applied the following and it is working. Now I have to figure out the parsing to google charts. Thank you for helping with the sum issue. I have added my code incase anyone else is having a similar issue.

```
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(created) FROM ost_ticket') as $opened);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(closed) FROM ost_ticket') as $closed1);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT SUM(isoverdue) FROM ost_ticket') as $overdue) 

echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>".$opened['COUNT(created)']."</td>", "<td>".$closed1['COUNT(closed)']."</td>", "<td>".$overdue['SUM(isoverdue)']."</td>";  
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: great, the _update dynamically_ part is pretty straight forward. probably easier to separate code into separate files. let me know if you have trouble...

Comment: Thank you. I am having a little trouble, but I am looking through the link you referenced. I have created a dbconnect file and separated it from the rest of the files. I am removing the google code from my count.php, so it will be on its own as well and then trying to make the google data work as per the link.