# Google Chart Data from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to generate one chart like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/x1rjLsav/

My PHP file return array like bellow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: 04 PM}, 747]
    [1] => [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: 05 PM}, 614]
    [2] => [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: 09 AM}, 1080]
    [3] => [{v: [10, 0, 0], f: 10 AM}, 1472]
    [4] => [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: 11 AM}, 1191]
    [5] => [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: 12 PM}, 1142]
    [6] => [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: 01 PM}, 1156]
    [7] => [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: 02 PM}, 1331]
    [8] => [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: 03 PM}, 885]
    [9] => [{v: [18, 0, 0], f: 06 PM}, 503]
    [10] => [{v: [19, 0, 0], f: 07 PM}, 333]
    [11] => [{v: [20, 0, 0], f: 08 PM}, 206]
    [12] => [{v: [21, 0, 0], f: 09 PM}, 205]
    [13] => [{v: [22, 0, 0], f: 10 PM}, 185]
    [14] => [{v: [23, 0, 0], f: 11 PM}, 141]
    [15] => [{v: [24, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 105]
    [16] => [{v: [25, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 74]
    [17] => [{v: [26, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 58]
    [18] => [{v: [27, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 80]
    [19] => [{v: [4, 0, 0], f: 04 AM}, 87]
    [20] => [{v: [5, 0, 0], f: 05 AM}, 115]
    [21] => [{v: [6, 0, 0], f: 06 AM}, 102]
    [22] => [{v: [7, 0, 0], f: 07 AM}, 131]
    [23] => [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: 08 AM}, 604]
)
```

I store this array in variable `jsonData` and, when I log that in `console`, I get the same output.

However, when I am adding this data into Chart as bellow I get and error:

> Every row given must be either null or an array.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Emails');
  data.addRows([jsonData]);
```

I Modify the PHP file and got bellow JSON output

```
[["[{v: [16, 0, 0], f: 04 PM}, 747]"],["[{v: [17, 0, 0], f: 05 PM}, 614]"],["[{v: [9, 0, 0], f: 09 AM
}, 1080]"],["[{v: [10, 0, 0], f: 10 AM}, 1472]"],["[{v: [11, 0, 0], f: 11 AM}, 1191]"],["[{v: [12, 0
, 0], f: 12 PM}, 1142]"],["[{v: [13, 0, 0], f: 01 PM}, 1156]"],["[{v: [14, 0, 0], f: 02 PM}, 1331]"]
,["[{v: [15, 0, 0], f: 03 PM}, 885]"],["[{v: [18, 0, 0], f: 06 PM}, 503]"],["[{v: [19, 0, 0], f: 07 PM
}, 333]"],["[{v: [20, 0, 0], f: 08 PM}, 206]"],["[{v: [21, 0, 0], f: 09 PM}, 205]"],["[{v: [22, 0, 0
], f: 10 PM}, 185]"],["[{v: [23, 0, 0], f: 11 PM}, 141]"],["[{v: [24, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 105]"],["[{v
: [25, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 74]"],["[{v: [26, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 58]"],["[{v: [27, 0, 0], f: 12 AM}, 80]"
],["[{v: [4, 0, 0], f: 04 AM}, 87]"],["[{v: [5, 0, 0], f: 05 AM}, 115]"],["[{v: [6, 0, 0], f: 06 AM}
, 102]"],["[{v: [7, 0, 0], f: 07 AM}, 131]"],["[{v: [8, 0, 0], f: 08 AM}, 604]"]]
```

and i Modify JAVA script as bellow, it should work but its not also not working.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Emails Opens');
  data.addRows(jsonData);
```

Comment: see the example under the [DataTable constructor method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1) for the json format google will accept -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) using php to build the json

Comment: Hello @WhiteHat i try this example before while searching & its not working. your output is different and my output required is different, see the above JS field how i need output. Please let me know how to get like this result. Thanks

Comment: not sure i follow the question, the fiddle link is blank and the posted 'array' doesn't look like valid json, javascript, or php. can you post the result of `console.log(jsonData);` ??

Comment: hello,  i need data rows in this format ata.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3],  and resule from your php code is coming like this   {"cols":[{"label":"Time of Day","type":"string"},{"label":"Emails","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"16"},{"f":"04 PM"},{"v":747}]},{"c":[{"v":"17"},{"f":"05 PM"},

Answer (score 1):

if you use this format...

`{"cols":[{"label":"Time of Day","type":"string"},{"label":"Emails","type":"number"}],"r‌​ows":[{"c":[{"v":"16‌​"},{"f":"04 PM"},{"v":747}]},{"c":[{"v":"17"},{"f":"05 PM"}...`

then you can create the data table directly...

`var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);`

with the following format...

`[{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1], [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2], [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3],...`

you need to first parse what most likely is a string,
into an actual array using `JSON.parse`...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
data.addColumn('number', 'Emails');
data.addRows(JSON.parse(jsonData));
```

Comment: thanks for your all effort but its not working. Please see the link what i am doing and whats wrong, i am trying to create a Google Chart with Date and value http://pastebin.com/Wdupyq3w

Comment: did you check my pastebin and see where is error ? Thanks

Comment: in the pastebin, the first json has several empty arrays (`,[],`) between all the rows, that won't work. the other json is invalid as well, appears to be a an array of strings (`[["[{v: [16, 0, 0], f: 04 PM}, 747]"]...`) <-- that would work, maybe, without the quotation marks...

Comment: Thanks for reply but 2nd array is also not working. i try every way but not working. could you please write little PHP to create results like https://jsfiddle.net/x1rjLsav/