# Google Charts Timeout reading data from php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I've a working example to graph data with google Charts.
It takes the data from a mysql database. If the timerange is of max a day it works great. If it's higher i get this error on the page:

"Cannot read property 'xB' of undefined"

If I execute the query from MySQL and request again the page, then it works. This why maybe MySQL is caching the query and answerring to the Google Chart Page the result faster.

How to deal with this error?

Here the simple code called for crating the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', "Average Pressure");
  data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
  data.addRows([
<?php
$type = "line";
include("fetch_data.php");
?>
  ]);
    // create formatter
    var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,##0.00'});
    // format column 1 - Pressure
    formatNumber.format(data, 1);
    // format column 2 - Temperature
    formatNumber.format(data, 2);
  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Average Pressure and Temperatures'
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.00'
    },
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    series: {
      // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
      0: {axis: 'Pressure'},
      1: {axis: 'Temperature'}
    },
    axes: {
      // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
      y: {
        Temps: {label: 'Pressure'},
        Daylight: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'}
      }
    }
  };
  function drawMaterialChart() {
    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
    var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(materialOptions));
  }
  drawMaterialChart();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The fetch_data calls the data to draw.

Thanks for the help!

Simon

**NEW UPDATE**

I've tried to use ajax to load data, taken from a working example I have and trying to adapt it on the above example. Here the new example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.50/fetch_data.php?type=gauge',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (jsonData) {
                var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                data.addColumn('number', "Average Pressure");
                data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
                data.addRows(jsonData);
                // create formatter
                var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,##0.00'});
                // format column 1 - Pressure
                formatNumber.format(data, 1);
                // format column 2 - Temperature
                formatNumber.format(data, 2);
                var materialOptions = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Average Pressure and Temperatures'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        format: '#,##0.00'
                    },
                    width: 1200,
                    height: 600,
                    series: {
                        // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
                        0: {axis: 'Pressure'},
                        1: {axis: 'Temperature'}
                    },
                    axes: {
                        // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
                        y: {
                            Temps: {label: 'Pressure'},
                            Daylight: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'}
                        }
                    }
                };

                function drawMaterialChart() {
                    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
                    var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
                    materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(materialOptions));
                }
                drawMaterialChart();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <br><br>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The fetch_data actually, if executed manually, returns the following output:

```
[[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 33, 00), 1014.89, 30.8],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 36, 00), 1014.81, 30.6],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 39, 00), 1014.82, 30.8],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 42, 00), 1014.76, 31.1],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 45, 00), 1014.7, 31],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 48, 00), 1014.67, 30.6],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 51, 00), 1014.73, 31],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 54, 00), 1014.74, 30.7],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 14, 57, 00), 1014.77, 30.5],
[new Date(2016, 08, 29, 15, 00, 00), 1014.75, 30.1], ]
```

The fetch_data is not called at all looking in the apache logs.
Any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Simon

Comment: have you considered using ajax to fetch the data from php? [here is a basic example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) -- otherwise, it would be helpful to see the result of `include("fetch_data.php");`...

Comment: Hello @WhiteHat , I've tried updating the example with ajax with no success. Above the example corrected with the content of the fetch_data. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: unfortunately, the above is not valid json -- using `dataType: 'json'` will trigger the `error:` callback, which isn't present above -- that's why the example i shared builds the entire table, not just the rows, and uses `json_encode` -- you could get around that if not for the dates...

Comment: Thannks @WhiteHat I got to work it based on your example and following it line per line.

Comment: cheers! glad you were able to resolve...