# call a JS function in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts

I have a js file contains the following code:

```
var BlankonDashboard = function () {

return {

    // =========================================================================
    // CONSTRUCTOR APP
    // =========================================================================
    init: function () {
        BlankonDashboard.visitorChart();
    },

    // =========================================================================
    // VISITOR CHART & SERVER STATUS
    // =========================================================================
    visitorChart: function () {
        if($('#visitor-chart').length){
            $.plot("#visitor-chart", [{
                label: "Vente Année N",
                color: "rgba(0, 177, 225, 0.35)",
                data: [
                    ["Jan", 420],
                    ["Fév", 532],
                    ["Mar", 367],
                    ["Avr", 245],
                    ["Mai", 674],
                    ["Jui", 897],
                    ["Juil", 745]
                ]
            }, {
                label: "Vente Année N-1",
                color: "rgba(233, 87, 63, 0.36)",
                data: [
                    ["Jan", 362],
                    ["Fév", 452],
                    ["Mar", 653],
                    ["Avr", 756],
                    ["Mai", 670],
                    ["Jui", 352],
                    ["Juil", 243]
                ]
            }], {
                series: {
                    lines: { show: false },
                    splines: {
                        show: true,
                        tension: 0.4,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        fill: 0.5
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 4
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: "transparent",
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent"
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: { content: "%x : %y" + " People" },
                xaxis: {
                    tickColor: "transparent",
                    mode: "categories"
                },
                yaxis: { tickColor: "transparent" },
                shadowSize: 0
            });
        }
    },
};

}();

// Call main app init
BlankonDashboard.init();
```

visitorChart function to draw a chart with static data but I want to do it dynamic with php, I don't know if I can migrate php data to js file (file.js), but if I can migrate php data to this function (visitorChart) that will be walk I think.

Comment: Ahhh....you could make an ajax call to get data in json format and initialize the chart after you get the data. take a look here https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/

Comment: Spit out the JavaScript from PHP or load it via Ajax with JSON.

Comment: but the problem is how I can call this function, you can see in this js file all function is into a variable `var BlankonDashboard = function () { ...}`

Comment: although a different chart library (google charts), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) shows how to build json in php and retrieve with ajax using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Ajax Request for this:

1. In PHP build a JSON with the information you need to receive in the
   view
2. Create an Ajax call (get) pointing to the URL that builds the
   JSON
3. Inject the JSON object into your code like this
   `$.plot("#visitor-chart", [ data ]);`

And that should be it :)

Of course that you need to make sure that the JSON comes EXACTLY in the same format that the chart is expecting.

;)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Agreed. That makes it seem overly complicated, on top of likely being the wrong team outright.

Comment: How else would you do it @Carcigenicate? Overly complicated? hahaha

Comment: @mkmnstr Not the process, just the name. Telling a noob they need to create a Web service might sound daunting. Id just say they need to make an AJAX request. Whatever. Not a big deal.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I apologize. Misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The first way would run slightly faster, however the second way could run again and again in js updating the data without reloading the page.

Way 1: 
somewhere at the start of the php file where this js is imported use the following code:

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo [your serialized data here] ?>
</script>
```

Note that if you import this js in multiple files, you can create a separate php file and include it everywhere.

Way 2:

Create a php which does a JSON serialization to your data. Also make user that in the headers you mention the file type as json. That is: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Then in your js file, wherever you need the data, just write

```
$.getJSON("yourfile.php", {parameter1: value1, parmeter2: value2}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```