# Google table 100 comes before 10 and 8 comes at the end

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I use Google table. 
When I sort it by number from 10 to 99 as seen in img 1, it orders nicely.

--- IMG 1 ----

[image]

But when I use one digit 1-9 or more than 100 it does not sort nicely as you can see in img 2.

---- IMG 2 ----

[image]

How can I fix the problem?

I use the following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'ID');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Image');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Image Size');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Order');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Actions');
    data.addRows([
<?php
if (count($slideshow))
{
    foreach($slideshow as $item)
    {
        $namelink = anchor("$module/admin/edit/".$item['id'],$item['name']);
        $subject = $item['image'];
        $imagename = getImageName($subject);
        $imagepath = getImagePath($subject);
        $filepath = base_url().$imagepath;
        $imagecont = "<img width=\"70px\" src=\'".$filepath."\' />";
        $filesize = getimagesize($imagepath);
        $filesizecont = "width: ".$filesize[0]. "px<br />height: ".$filesize[1]. "px";
        $item = str_replace("'", "\'", $item);
        /* $public_icon = ($item['public']==1 ? 'tick':'cross'); */
        /* $publiclink = anchor("kaimonokago/admin/changecatBooleanStatus/$module/".$item['id']."/public",$this->bep_assets->icon($public_icon), array('class' => $item['public']. ' changestatus')); */
        $active_icon = ($item['status']=='active'?'tick':'cross');
        $statuslink = anchor("kaimonokago/admin/changeStatus/$module/".$item['id'],$this->bep_assets->icon($active_icon), array('class' => $item['status']. ' changestatus'));
        $editlink = anchor($module.'/admin/edit/'.$item['id'],$this->bep_assets->icon('pencil'));
        if ($item['status']=='inactive')
        {
            $deletelink = anchor('kaimonokago/admin/delete/'.$module.'/'.$item['id'],$this->bep_assets->icon('delete'), array("class" => "delete_link","onclick"=>"return confirmSubmit(\'".$item['name']."\')"));
        }
        else
        {
            $deletelink ='';
        }
        //$link = "testing";  
        echo "['".$item['id']."','".$namelink."','".$imagecont."','".$filesizecont."','".$item['slide_order']."','".$statuslink."','".$editlink.$deletelink."' ],\n";
    }
}
?>
]);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml:true,width:'100%'});
}
</script>
 <div id='table_div'></div>
<script>
$(window).resize(function(){
    drawTable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: looks like sorting by string and not by number.

Comment: you need to change order from string to whatever the value for integer is: `data.addColumn('string', 'Order');`

Answer (score 2):

Your order is being sorted as a string because of this line:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Order');
```

This needs to be changed to make the order sort as a number:

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Order');
```

[More information](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to changing the column type to `'number'`...

`data.addColumn('number', 'Order');`

need to remove the surrounding quotes from the column when loading the row data...

from --> `'".$item['slide_order']."'`

to --> `'.$item['slide_order'].'`

in following line...

```
echo "['".$item['id']."','".$namelink."','".$imagecont."','".$filesizecont."','.$item['slide_order'].','".$statuslink."','".$editlink.$deletelink."' ],\n";
```

**note**: recommend using ajax to get data from php to javascript, rather than mixing in the same file

[here is a full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771), which includes building json in a format google accepts

Comment: nice catch with the quotes