# How I create a pie chart based on COUNT(php + mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

I have this database. I wanted to generate pie chart based from this database. The pie chart will generate based from the COUNT function. Can you help me to solve this?

Database Structure

[image]

Here the code.The main page of my form.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error!");
mysql_select_db("try_pie_chart");

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PIE CHART</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="count" action="piechart_post.php" method="post">


            <select name="month">

 <option value="01">January</option>
 <option value="02">February</option>
 <option value="03">March</option>
 <option value="04">April</option>
 <option value="05">May</option>
 <option value="06">June</option>
 <option value="07">July</option>
 <option value="08">August</option>
 <option value="09">September</option>
 <option value="10">October</option>
 <option value="11">November</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" name="year" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" onclick = "<?php $month=$_POST['month'] ?><?php $year=$_POST['year'] ?>"/>

 </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here the code for form action. It will give output of COUNT

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error");
mysql_select_db("try_pie_chart");

?>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PIE CHART</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php $month=$_POST['month'] ?><?php $year=$_POST['year'] ?>
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_details WHERE purpose='COURSES' AND (MONTH(date) LIKE '%$month' AND YEAR(date) LIKE '%$year%')") or die ("Error!");

 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_details WHERE purpose='BRIEFING' AND (MONTH(date) LIKE '%$month' AND YEAR(date) LIKE '%$year%')") or die ("Error!");

 $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_details WHERE purpose='COMPETITION' AND (MONTH(date) LIKE '%$month' AND YEAR(date) LIKE '%$year%')") or die ("Error!");

 $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_details WHERE purpose='INTERVIEW' AND (MONTH(date) LIKE '%$month' AND YEAR(date) LIKE '%$year%')") or die ("Error!");

$result5 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_details WHERE purpose='OTHERS' AND (MONTH(date) LIKE '%$month' AND YEAR(date) LIKE '%$year%')") or die ("Error!");

$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_details WHERE (MONTH(date) LIKE '%$month' AND YEAR(date) LIKE '%$year%')") or die ("Error!");

?>

 <?php 
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
  $row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
 $row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4);
 $row5=mysql_fetch_array($result5);
 $row6=mysql_fetch_array($result6);

 ?>

  <table width="41%" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td width="8%">BIL</td>
  <td width="42%">PURPOSE</td>
  <td width="50%">TOTAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>COURSES</td>
  <td><?php echo $row['total'];  ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>BRIEFING</td>
   <td><?php echo $row2['total'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>COMPETITION</td>
   <td><?php echo $row3['total'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>INTERVIEW</td>
    <td><?php echo $row4['total'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>OTHERS</td>
     <td><?php echo $row5['total'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">Total Overall</td>
    <td><strong><?php echo $row6['total'];  ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </table>



     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) of using ajax to get json from php and draw a google chart using javascript

Comment: I dont have any basic of ajax. Not understand the code sir.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of framework available to create chart using php mysql jquery css

Few of them i'm listing here

```
http://www.chartjs.org/ 
https://developers.google.com/chart/
https://d3js.org/
https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/
https://n3-charts.github.io/line-chart/#/home
http://www.highcharts.com/
```

You can use one of them which serve your purpose, I'm using chartJs, HighChart and Google Chart, if you want to make more complex chart then you can go for D3 also.

I'm Giving you example how to create chart using highchart.

```js
$(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                    y: 56.33
                }, {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 24.03
                }, {
                    name: 'Firefox',
                    y: 10.38
                }, {
                    name: 'Safari',
                    y: 4.77
                }, {
                    name: 'Opera',
                    y: 0.91
                }, {
                    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                    y: 0.2
                }]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Here i passed `data` as json array

```
[{
   name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
   y: 56.33
}, {
    name: 'Chrome',
    y: 24.03
}, {
    name: 'Firefox',
    y: 10.38
}, {
    name: 'Safari',
    y: 4.77
}, {
    name: 'Opera',
    y: 0.91
}, {
    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
    y: 0.2
}]
```

You can replace this array with your own data, you can convert php array to json using `json_encode($your_php_array_goes_here)` it will return json formatted array.

Comment: but how sir? I dont have any basic of Javasript language

Comment: please check above code and run it you will get idea how to generate chart, ask me if you need help.

Comment: sir. i cannot understand. i just understand part where to build the chart, but i dont have any idea to convert the json to php.

Comment: how to change to percentage to normal number?

Comment: what you have tried so far after i written code snippet ?

Comment: no need sir! already works! hehehe. I already make it!. Thank youuuuuuu.

Comment: Sir. One more question. How we gonna label the part of the pie? Such as, I wanna the part of pie will have the number of the percentage.

Comment: Yes. your answer helped me. Sir. One more question. How we gonna label the part of the pie chart? Such as, I wanna the part of pie will have the number of the percentage.

Comment: I already enable the label at the slice of the pie chart, but the number of purpose didnot appear. Only the name of the label appear at the slice

Comment: I want vote your answer, but cannot. denied by the system. because my reputation is not enough