# How to parse cURL response into JSON for Google charts to read

Tags: php, json, curl, charts, draw

So basically I'm doing a cURL request to get a JSON object. This is my getData.php file:

```
     <?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mfdewfewffewfefef.com/api/dataout/IAfhAfTIUZrCje5q.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-Startdate: 2016-10-04 00:00:00";
$headers[] = "X-Enddate: 2016-10-08 15:00:00";
$headers[] = "X-Channelnum: 2";
$headers[] = "X-Reclimit: 50";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: cwfewfewf/1.0";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

And I'm getting the response: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEzho.png

Basically this are values measured with a termal sensor. The "ts" is the time it was measured, and "value" the actual value.

Now I'm trying to draw a Google chart with this info, but I'm not being able to do it. This is my chart.html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I just get a blank page. On the Google Charts documentation it says that the getData.php can be anything provided that its on json format, and the curl response I'm outputing on getData.php is in JSON format.

Or do I need to make some changes to make the chart only read the "ts" and the "value" information and draw the chart?

Comment: The url https://xxx.sasasaas.pt/api/dataout/ffwefewfewff.json doesn't seems to fetch any data

Comment: Edit with the correct values to fetch the data. @Kiran Muralee

Comment: replace src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" with src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" and try again

Comment: [here is a full example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) of using ajax to get json from php in [a format google accepts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the requirement from OP I have made changes to the `chart.html` as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "getData.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

                jsonData = jsonData.channels[2].values;

                var dataArray = [['ts', 'values']];
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
                {
                    var tempArray = [jsonData[i].ts, parseFloat(jsonData[i].value.replace(",", "."))];
                    dataArray.push(tempArray);
                }

                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                        dataArray
                        );                

                var options = {
                    hAxis: {title: 'TIME->  "TS" Variable', titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
                    vAxis: {title: 'Values', titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}}

                };

                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested the code in my system and the chart is drawn as given below

[image]

Comment: the returned data is not suitable to be used for creating a data table.

Comment: explain what values from the returned JSON data that you need to construct your data table

Comment: @user2535046 I have made changes to the code to fulfill your requirement.Check

Comment: @user2535046 glad to know :).Mark answer as accepted if it was helpful to you

Comment: what if i want to draw 2 lines on the chart? Get the data using cURL too, but had 2 lines, with 2 different types of data. How can i do this?

Comment: @user2535046 Sorry I don't get it.By line what do you mean. Can you elaborate more like what you really want,what have you tried etc.May be you should post it as a new question.