# google bar chart not showing values from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, google-visualization

I am using google chart API and using php mysql for populating the bar chart.
My front end is :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Visualization API and the line package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getData.php',

        success: function (data1) {
        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      data.addColumn('number', 'State');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Status');
      data.addColumn('number', 'City');

      var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);

      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([jsonData[i].state, parseInt(jsonData[i].status), parseInt(jsonData[i].city)]);
      }
      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Users',
          subtitle: 'Users registered'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }

      };
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('bar_chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
       }
     });
    }
  </script>
    <div id="bar_chart"></div>
```

My getData.php file have:

```
$sql = "SELECT `state`,`status`,`city` FROM `user`";

$sth = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));


$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth);
print_r(json_encode($row,true));
```

I am getting the values from the database in my success function but not able to print it in the chart

Comment: have tried echoing the value `jsonData[i].state` in windows console what are you getting. also try echoing the `data1` in windows console. What you get?

Comment: @AhmedKhan it showing data in if i alert data1. but in window console its not showing data in jsonData[i].state or status or city

Comment: in console try echoing `jsonData` whole what you get

Comment: try building json in the format google accepts, then you can create the DataTable directly, with no client side manipulation -- see this [full example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) of using ajax to get json from php and draw a chart