# Only drawing Google Charts in specific cases (alternative to setOnLoadCallback)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I have a page that should be able to visualize data in three different ways. The first is a pie chart, the second is a line chart, and the third is raw text (no chart at all).

I have the code below in my `<head>`.

I want to call `drawChart()` from php, but when I do, it doesn't know the global (?) variables `chart`, `data` and `options`.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(calcChart);
        var chart, data, options;
        function calcChart() {
            anss = ["seg1", "seg2", "seg3"];
            freqs = ["2", "3", "3"];
            console.log("<?php echo '>> ' . $ansarray . ' <<'; ?>");

            var freqarr = [['Segment', 'Size']];
            for (var i = 0; i < anss.length; i++) {
                ans = anss[i];
                frq = parseInt(freqs[i]);
                freqarr.push([ans, frq]);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < freqarr.length; i++) {
                console.log(freqarr[i]);
            }
            data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(freqarr);

            options = {
                title: 'Antwoorden'
            };

            chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        }
        function drawChart() {
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```

And this is only the first step: the next step is to fill the chart with data that php gets from a MySQL database. How can I do so?

Comment: [here is a full example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) of using php to build json data for drawing google charts...