# Google Bar Chart from Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a mysql db with 3 fields region(vachar), new_customers(int) and old_customers(int).

I am trying to create a bar chart with google charts and php but it doesn't work. I think i am doing sth wrong on echo.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);

 function drawMaterial() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Region', 'New Customers', 'Old Customers'],
 <?php 
 $query = "SELECT sum(new_customers) AS new, sum(old_customers) AS old, region FROM daily GROUP BY region";

 $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['region']."',";

 echo "['".$row['new']."',";

 echo "['".$row['old']."',";

 }
 ?>
 ]);

 var options = {

 title: 'Country wise new and returned visitors',

 bars: 'horizontal'
 };
 var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));
 material.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you get any value after executing your query?

Comment: Yeap query works OK it returns the following rows: new old region, 8 6 america, 2 4 asia, 127 67 europe

Comment: Try querying outside the drawMaterial function, and first format the data according to the necessary structure and then put it inside the drawMaterial function. It seems like something is wrong with your function.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I used these examples which i managed to work except bar charts http://www.voidtricks.com/create-google-charts-from-mysql-db/

Comment: What I meant is get your php query to run outside the function `drawMaterial` and assign into a variable. Then inside the `drawMaterial` just append the value rather running php query. I am not sure how much effective running php code inside the script blog. Although it could be effective but a bad coding practice.

Comment: recommend not mixing the php and javascript, use ajax instead -- see this [full example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) of using ajax to get data from php and draw a google chart...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the chart is not taking the three parameters in the data variable.
At the moment you have it like: `['Region', 'New Customers', 'Old Customers'],`.

Change it to:  **`['Region', 'New Customers']`**,.

In the `while loop`, PHP is not recognising any column with the name `$row['new']` or `$row['old']`. Instead use indexes and change your echo to:
**`echo "['".$row[2]." [".$row[0]."]', ".$row[1]."],`";**

I would also recommend you to have the sql query outside the function and have only the iteration through the sql results (the `while loop` with the `echo`).

Also, you were not loading the charts properly. You forgot to add the word 'charts':

```
  google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);
```

This is the final solution:

```
<?php
include("YOUR PHP CONNECT FILE");

$query = "SELECT sum(new_customers) AS new, sum(old_customers) AS old, region FROM daily GROUP BY region";
$exec = mysqli_query($YOURCONNECTIONVARIABLE ,$query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);

       function drawMaterial() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Region', 'New Customers'],
        <?php 
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
            echo "['".$row[2]." [".$row[0]."]', ".$row[1]."],";  
          }
        ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Country wise new and returned visitors',
          bars: 'horizontal'
        };

        var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));
          material.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="barchart" style="width: 100%; height: 40em;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.