# willing to add columns to dataTable required for drawing line chart using google visualization

Tags: php, html, google-visualization

I'm having 4 php variables and according to the value stored in them, I require to have the line chart to have the line corresponding to he variable.
For eg: date, temperature and humidity are the columns in my sql database table.
So, I have php variable $temperature and $humidity respectively for temperature and humidity. If $temperaure store y then line chart would contain line showing temperature and the same goes for humidity.
If the variables store y the lines for both huimidity and temperature would be displayed in the same chart.

Can someone please help to achieve this.....

Code showing lines for all the columns in the line chart:

```html
<?php
session_start();
 //have made connection to sql database......using $connect variable...
//$tablename =  $_SESSION['usertable'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM raam";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});


   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(line_chart);

    function line_chart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                          ['date_time', 'temperature','moisture','humidity'],

                          <?php
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                               echo " ['".$row["date_time"]."', ".$row["temperature"].",".$row["moisture"].",".$row["humidity"]."], ";

                          }
                          ?>
                     ]);
         var options = {

          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
           }


</script>
</head>

<body>

<br /><br />
           <div style="width:900px;">
                <h3 align="center"> FIELD TEMPERATURE  </h3>
                <br />
                <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
           </div>

</body>
</html>
```

code that I had thought to work.....

```html
<?php
//session_start();
 //have made connection to sql database......using $con variable...
//$tablename =  $_SESSION['usertable'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM raam";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$temperature = "y";
$moisture = "y";
$humidity = "y";
$motor = "y";
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});


   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(line_chart);

   function pie_chart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                          ['date_time' 

  <?php if( $temperature == "Y" || $temperature == "y"){ ?>
   ,'temperature'
  <?php } if( $moisture == "Y" || $moisture == "y"){ ?>
   ,'moisture'
  <?php } if( $humidity == "Y" || $thumidity == "y"){ ?>
   ,'humidity'
  <?php } if( $motor == "Y" || $motor == "y"){ ?>
   ,'motor'

  <?php } ?> 
   ],

                          <?php
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                               echo "['".$row["date_time"];

    if( $temperature == "Y" || $temperature == "y")
     {echo ."', ".$row["temperature"];}
    if( $moisture == "Y" || $moisture == "y")
     {echo ."', ".$row["moisture"];}
    if( $humidity == "Y" || $thumidity == "y")
     {echo ."', ".$row["humidity"];}
    if( $motor == "Y" || $motor == "y")
     {echo ."', ".$row["motor"];}
         
    echo ."],";
                          }
                          ?>
                     ]);


         var options = {

          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
           }


</script>
</head>

<body>

<br /><br />
           <div style="width:900px;">
                <h3 align="center"> FIELD TEMPERATURE  </h3>
                <br />
                <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
           </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: recommend not mixing php and javascript in the same file -- instead, have php in separate file that returns json data, then get the json using ajax from javascript -- [see this full example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771), includes drawing the chart...

Comment: Is there any way to do it in the manner I had tried?......as T haven't used json much so I'm not getting the idea of how can I split the code in php and javascript