# Generating dynamic stats with google charts

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, graph, google-visualization

I'd like to know whether it is possible to make simple and dynamic graphs with google charts; here what i am using actually:

Oracle DB, JSTL, EL, JSP pages.

What else should be in the sphere of my knowledge in order to realise the result mentioned above.

**EDIT:**

I'm going to gather data from the ORACLE databse through JPQL they will be stored in a list of Object[] containing a name and a number for each row, they will be sent a JSP page through servlet: `request.setAttribute("data",listemployees);`
How can acces to this list from the JSP and how do i store them in the javascript code generating the chart.

**EDIT: Adding details**

This is the DAO part, selecting the type of tickets and counting them.

```
private static final String JPQL_SELECT_TICKETS_ETAT = "SELECT t.etat, COUNT(t.id_ticket) FROM Ticket t GROUP BY t.etat";

@PersistenceContext( unitName = "bdd_helpdesk_PU" )
private EntityManager       em;


public List<Object[]> chargerTicketsParEtat() throws DAOException {
    List<Object[]> liste;
    //List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("").getResultList();
    TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(JPQL_SELECT_TICKETS_ETAT, Object[].class);
    //query.setParameter(PARAM_TICKET, id_ticket);
    try {
        liste = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    return liste;
}
```

Next code happens in servlet:

```
        List<Object[]> lticket = ticketDao.chargerTicketsParEtat();
        String test= "this is a string";
        request.setAttribute("test", test);
        request.setAttribute("lticket",lticket);
```

And this is the JSP page:

The result is represented in numbers in a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Etat ticket</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${lticket}" var="ticket">
<tr>
<td>${ticket[0]}</td>
<td>${ticket[1]}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

And this is the kind of hart i'm going to use:

```
  <head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

It is placed in head, I'd like to know what language should i use to be able to inject the data that is represented in the table into the chart's script, all i know is the EL ( expression langugae ) can't be placed in the script because it's interpreted in the server part while the js is interpreted by the browser
**NEW SERVLET:**`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "nocache");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");


        List<Object[]> lticket = ticketDao.chargerTicketsParEtat();


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try{

            json.put("status", 200);
            json.put("msg", "OK");  

            JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
            String nom="Non défini";
            long valeur;
            for (Object[] result : lticket) {

                if((int)result[0]==1)
                    nom="En attente de prise en charge";
                else if((int)result[0]==2)
                    nom="En attente de validation";
                else if((int)result[0]==3)
                    nom="Cloturé";
                else if((int)result[0]==4)
                    nom="En cours de traitement";
                valeur = (long) result[1];
                map.put(nom,valeur);
            }
            json.put("map", map);

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.print(json.toString());
        request.setAttribute("lticket", lticket);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile2.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

**JSP PAGE:**

```
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsonData = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "/test", success: function(result){
            jsonData = result.map;
        }});
    });

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    for (var key in jsonData) {
        data.addRow([key,jsonData[key]]);
       }

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

      </body>
```

`

Comment: yeah you can make the charts dynamic, you can use ajax calls to get the dynamic data and set or update it appropriately.

Comment: Okay, the data is sent through Http Requests and can be read through Expression Language ( EL ) how do i add data in the JS script?

Comment: you need to define a url which can serve a json response with the data for Google charts which then you easily make use of through ajax call from the page and update the chart. Please add your existing code so that I can show how it can be done in your case

Comment: take the approach mentioned above, format the json as [found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) to avoid manipulation on the client -- although php, [here is a full example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) showing the workflow...

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar Actually I'm trieing to write code, i'm searching over the web how to store request data coming from servlet into JSON object.

Comment: Seriously about 4 hours looking for a way to make dynamic charts and still can't figure out how, all dynamic charts examples over the web have already defined array data, i have no idea how this can be called "dynamic", i'll give you an example, i'm going to gather data from the ORACLE databse through JPQL they will be stored in a list of Object[] containing a name and a number for each row, they will be sent a JSP page through servlet: `request.setAttribute("data",listemployees);`
How can acces to this list from the JSP and how do i store them in the javascript code generating the chart.

Comment: Can you please post your existing code ? It's difficult to understand where you are stuck without code.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar It's all up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the DAO part you don't need to change anything.

For servlet you need to return a json like this :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ChartsDataServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "nocache");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try{

            json.put("status", 200);
            json.put("msg", "OK");  

            JSONObject map = new JSONObject();

            map.put("Mushrooms", 3);
            map.put("Onions", 1);
            map.put("Olives", 1);
            map.put("Zucchini", 1);
            map.put("Pepperoni", 2);
            json.put("map", map);

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.print(json.toString());
    }
}
```

And then use this servlet-url(say `chartsDataUrl`) on the page you want to draw the charts.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var jsonData = [];
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({url: "/chartsDataUrl", success: function(result){
               jsonData = result.map;
           }});
       });


      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        for (var key in jsonData) {
          data.addRow([key,jsonData[key]]);
         }

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I procceeded to use JSON as you mentioned above, the JSP's chart does'nt show data, a "no data" appears on the page, i added description in the post, check from "NEW SERVLET" and thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Please add some console statement and let me know if you get any errors in javascript console.

Comment: also please remove these two lines  from servlet   request.setAttribute("lticket", lticket);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile2.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: you servlet should only output a json response and you are setting attribute and dispatching the request, that would make the whole thing futile.

Comment: you use only one of them and not both.

Comment: Now i'm getting only this line when executing: {"msg":"OK","map":{"Zucchini":1,"Onions":1,"Mushrooms":3,"Olives":1,"Pepperoni":2},"status":200}
The browser's console displays this:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:4040/monprojet2/test".

Comment: ( And btw i already edited the Ajax URL to /monprojet2/test )

Comment: put some console.log() in javascript for chart check if ajax call is fetching the data from servlet.

Comment: All this time i was accessing the servlet url, and i had to access the JSP.
By accessing the view's URL it works, thanks for your assistance mate.

Comment: Oh can't i gather two distinct maps from one servlet?

Comment: sure you can. just define the other map with a different name and proceed like we have done for the first one.