# How to populate google chart with this dynamic array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, google-visualization

I want to learn how to populate a google chart from an array that is based on a sql query. The array can contain different number of results depending on what day it is run. I created the chart with manual input data so I know it works but when I try to read data from the array I don't succeed.

This is the array

```
Array

(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mobillyftar
            [PRODUCT_GROUP] => Mobillyftar
            [1] => 20
            [WEEK] => 20
            [2] => 54
            [QTY] => 54
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Selar
            [PRODUCT_GROUP] => Selar
            [1] => 20
            [WEEK] => 20
            [2] => 808
            [QTY] => 808
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Taklyftar
            [PRODUCT_GROUP] => Taklyftar
            [1] => 20
            [WEEK] => 20
            [2] => 6
            [QTY] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tillb & res
            [PRODUCT_GROUP] => Tillb & res
            [1] => 20
            [WEEK] => 20
            [2] => 1159
            [QTY] => 1159
        )

)
```

And here is my chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw);

<?php 
$variable = $producedPerProductgroupAndWeekArray; 
echo "var array=".$variable.";";
?>

function draw() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','week');
data.addColumn('number', 'qty'); 


for (idx=0;idx=array[1].lenght;idx++)
    {
        data.addRow([array[1][idx].week,Number(array[1][idx].qty)]);
        <!--data.addRow([table[idx].week,Number(table[idx.value])]);-->
        <!--data.addRow( [table[0][WEEK], Number(table[0][QTY]) ] );-->
    }

var option = {
    chart:{
        title:"barchart",
    }, 
    bars:'vertical',
}

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("bar"))
chart.draw(data,option);
}
</script>

<div id="bar" style="height:500px; width:900px;"></div>
```

Comment: recommend using ajax to get json data from php, [using this format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), you can create the data table directly, with no manipulation in javascript -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)

Answer (score 0):

recommend building the array in php, similar to following...

```
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array();
$table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'WEEK', 'type' => 'string');
$table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Mobillyftar', 'type' => 'number');
$table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Selar', 'type' => 'number');
$table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Taklyftar', 'type' => 'number');
$table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Tillb', 'type' => 'number');

$row = array();
$row[] = array('v' => '20');
$row[] = array('v' => 54);
$row[] = array('v' => 808);
$row[] = array('v' => 6);
$row[] = array('v' => 1159);
$table['rows'] = array('c' => $row);
```

which should result in the following json...

```
{"cols":[
  {"label":"WEEK","type":"string"},
  {"label":"Mobillyftar","type":"number"},
  {"label":"Selar","type":"number"},
  {"label":"Taklyftar","type":"number"},
  {"label":"Tillb","type":"number"}
],
"rows":[
  {"c":[{"v":"20"},{"v":54},{"v":808},{"v":6},{"v":1159}]}
]}
```

which can then be used to create the data table directly...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = {
    "cols":[
      {"label":"WEEK","type":"string"},
      {"label":"Mobillyftar","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Selar","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Taklyftar","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Tillb","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
      {"c":[{"v":"20"},{"v":54},{"v":808},{"v":6},{"v":1159}]}
    ]
  };

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Wow thats very helpful. Can't wait to try it tomorrow.