# php google gauge data visualisation MySQL refresh issue.

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I am making a program to log temperature and humidity. I would like a live output of the data on the google gauges. I am using php to access MySQL. The issue i am running into is that I want the data to be called every 5 seconds and update the gauge. The gauge only updates once what am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['TEMP', <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "datalogger";
$password = "datalogger";
$dbname = "datalogger";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT temperature FROM logger ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["temperature"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?> ],
          ['Memory', 7],
          ['CPU', 55],
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0 ,1 , <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "datalogger";
$password = "datalogger";
$dbname = "datalogger";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT temperature FROM logger ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["temperature"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
);
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your setInterval() code, should be window.setInterval(function, milliseconds);

Comment: There are 2 other gauges and they are just using a random number and the are updating just fine. I get the 1 update at 5 seconds (5000ms) but after that the gauge thats coded into mysql doesn't update.

Comment: Yes, but the setInterval() you are showing in your code above has no time interval set.

Comment: its the 5000 after the chart.data that ends the mysql call.

Comment: Ah, quite buried, but you're right. What happens if you separate that function out so it reads setInterval(temperatureChecker(), 5000);

Comment: I tried making...

Comment: function tempChecker(){ ~~~All the php SQL stuff~~~} and the next lines down bottom now the function does not even update once.
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, tempChecker());
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);

Comment: try moving everything, even the 'data.setValue()' block to your tempChecker() so that you can pass setInterval(tempChecker(),5000);

Comment: php executes once on the server, when the page loads on the client, the php code is gone and only what it produced remains -- so calling `setInterval` will not re-execute the php, it will only load the original temperature value over and over -- you should separate the php from javascript and use ajax to get the data, then you could `setInterval` on the ajax code, which would work great -- [here is a full example for using ajax to get json data from php and draw a google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)

Comment: This explains a lot. So my core program is in python and it reads temperature set points from the table and compares them to the data and picks heat or cool. My new question is should I continue using mysql for this or should I change the database to make the user interface more easy to program? Just a side note the core program is complete and runs perfectly.

Comment: will the json file continue to update from the database? or will that only run once?

Comment: @Rich427 the script will call the JSON continuously.