# Populate google.visualization.arrayToDataTable with array

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm new to `PHP` and google Charts. Thanks in advance for your help.

I would like to get help converting an array `$votedata` I populate with code below:

```
array_push(
    $votedata,
    array(
        "Plats" => $name,
        "Bra" => $val1,
        "Ok" => $val2,
        "Neutral" => $val3,
        "Dålig" => $val4
    )
);
```

If I `print_r($votedata);` it looks like below so guess its ok:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Plats] => AAA [Bra] => 4 [Ok] => 0 [Neutral] => 2 [Dålig] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Plats] => BBB [Bra] => 7 [Ok] => 0 [Neutral] => 1 [Dålig] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Plats] => CCC [Bra] => 2 [Ok] => 3 [Neutral] => 1 [Dålig] => 6 )
)
```

How do I convert it to work with code below?

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      //<?php
      //    Convert and use $votedata;
      //?>
    ]);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `foreach` to print out each row...

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Plats", "Bra", "Ok", "Neutral", "Dålig"],

  <?php
    foreach ($votedata as $row) {
  ?>

    [<?="'".$row['Plats']."'"?>, <?=$row['Bra']?>, <?=$row['Ok']?>, <?=$row['Neutral']?>, <?=$row['Dålig']?>],

  <?php
    }
  ?>

  ]);
...
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly fine. Was hoping for a way to convert the array but will use your answer instead. Thanks alot.

Comment: cheers! but i normally wouldn't recommend mixing php within javascript -- check out this [full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) for using ajax instead