# Show google chart on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have the following div on a page where I would like a google chart to load on a button click:

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header"><b>System Voltage</b></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="line_chart" style="width:100%;height:360px;">
                    <!-- SHOW GOOGLE GRAPH HERE --> <button class="btn">Plot chart!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Google Chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart
        }).then(function drawChart() {

        <?php
        $imei = $bboxx_imei;
        $result = shell_exec('Daily_Data_Retriever_ishackweb.py ' . $imei);
        $resultdata = json_decode($result, true);
        ?>

        var jsonData =  <?php echo $result; ?>   //{"Battery Voltage, (V)":{"2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z":12.5,"2017-10-09T00:01:00.000Z":12.44,"2017-10-09T00:02:00.000Z":12.43}};

        var chartData = [];
        Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (column) {
        chartData.push(['Datetime', column]);
        Object.keys(jsonData[column]).forEach(function (dateValue) {
          chartData.push([new Date(dateValue), jsonData[column][dateValue]]);
        });
        });
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
        chartArea: {width:'90%', height:'65%'},
        title: 'Battery Voltage',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

At the moment, the button appears, but nothing is happening on the click. 
I am trying to follow this [example](https://codepen.io/OneToughCookie/pen/WbNyVg).

EDIT:

I have updated the google charts to exclude the callback statement, and also added libraries I am using. The chart shows up perfectly well when not using the button, but I would like it to show only when the button is pressed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart']
        }).then(function () {

        <?php
        $imei = $bboxx_imei;
        $result = shell_exec('Daily_Data_Retriever_ishackweb.py ' . $imei);
        $resultdata = json_decode($result, true);
        ?>

        var jsonData =  {"Battery Voltage, (A)":{"2017-11-11T00:00:00.000Z":12.3,"2017-11-11T00:01:00.000Z":12.35,"2017-11-11T00:02:00.000Z":12.6,"2017-11-11T00:03:00.000Z":12.7,"2017-11-11T00:04:00.000Z":12.8},"Battery Current, (A)":{"2017-11-11T00:00:00.000Z":1.3,"2017-11-11T00:01:00.000Z":1.4,"2017-11-11T00:02:00.000Z":1.5,"2017-11-11T00:03:00.000Z":1.6,"2017-11-11T00:04:00.000Z":1.7}};

        var chartData = [];
        Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (column) {
        chartData.push(['Datetime', column]);
        Object.keys(jsonData[column]).forEach(function (dateValue) {
          chartData.push([new Date(dateValue), jsonData[column][dateValue]]);
        });
        });
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
        chartArea: {width:'90%', height:'65%'},
        title: 'Battery Voltage',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Libraries:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using the promise returned from the `load` statement,
the `callback` is not needed...

change the load statement as follows...

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart'],
    }).then(function () {
```

also need to ensure the library is included...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

note: the following library is old and should no longer be used, you can remove it.
`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`
see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) for more info...

---

the `load` statement will wait for the document to load,
no need for --> `$(document).ready`

recommend loading google first, then wait for the button click...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    var jsonData = {"Battery Voltage, (V)":{"2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z":12.5,"2017-10-09T00:01:00.000Z":12.44,"2017-10-09T00:02:00.000Z":12.43}};

    var chartData = [];
    Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (column) {
    chartData.push(['Datetime', column]);
    Object.keys(jsonData[column]).forEach(function (dateValue) {
      chartData.push([new Date(dateValue), jsonData[column][dateValue]]);
    });
    });
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

    var options = {
      chartArea: {width:'90%', height:'65%'},
      title: 'Battery Voltage',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Draw Chart" />
<div id="line_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not showing after your updates (see edit). Could it possible the php code that is collecting the data?

Comment: see __EDIT__ above -- you can also check the browser's console for errors (F12) -- as for the php, i would personally not recommend mixing within javascript, instead use ajax from javascript to call the php page to get the data -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)...

Comment: your code works perfectly, thanks. I am now trying to add an extra line to the chart - see my edit for adding in data for "Battery Current, (A)", but I keep getting a `c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function` error. How can I adjust your chartData function to include the extra data?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457206/converting-json-data-for-google-chart-datatable?noredirect=1#comment81868981_47457206 - hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to import all the necessary files.  Make sure you are importing the jquery cdn (or download the file to your server)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

and google chart cdn

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

and check if you need an API key to use the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">` to the head of your html page to load the library for the chart