# Convert json data for google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to convert this json into the correct format for a google chart:

```
var jsonData =  {"Battery Voltage, (A)":
                    {"2017-11-11T00:00:00.000Z":12.3
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:01:00.000Z":12.35
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:02:00.000Z":12.6
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:03:00.000Z":12.7
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:04:00.000Z":12.8}
                ,"Battery Current, (A)":
                    {"2017-11-11T00:00:00.000Z":1.3
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:01:00.000Z":1.4
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:02:00.000Z":1.5
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:03:00.000Z":1.6
                    ,"2017-11-11T00:04:00.000Z":1.7}};
```

I can use this code, as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182697/show-google-chart-on-button-click/47187318?noredirect=1#comment81351822_47187318):

```
var chartData = [];
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (column) {
  chartData.push(['Datetime', column]);
  Object.keys(jsonData[column]).forEach(function (dateValue) {
    chartData.push([new Date(dateValue), jsonData[column][dateValue]]);
  });
});
```

But I get a `c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function` error.

How do I correctly format this data into a googe datatable?

Comment: Try without `new Date( )`