# Can a trend-line be applied to only a selected number of columns on a google chart

Tags: google-visualization

take for example I have the below chart which includes a trendline depicting the trend for an employee's progress over the course of a week.[employee progress chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anfWv.png)

the values for each day are brought in from a database as an INT datatype and the trendline acts accordingly. However, if an employees progress value is 0, how do I stop the trendline from acknowledging this and trending only to values above 0?

Comment: try using a `null` value in place of zero...

Comment: @WhiteHatI have attempted this but placing one the of the values as NULL, however, google charts has decided it's having none of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trendlines will ignore `null` values,
use `null` in place of zero.

see following working snippets...

---

**with zero** `0`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Amount'],
    [1, 100],
    [2, 4000],
    [3, 250],
    [4, 2400],
    [5, 0]
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    trendlines: {0: {}}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**with null** `null`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Amount'],
    [1, 100],
    [2, 4000],
    [3, 250],
    [4, 2400],
    [5, null]
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    trendlines: {0: {}}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah it has actually! thanks, now I just need to find a way to bring this in from the database!

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow tried to upvote it but it doesn't show it

Comment: no problem, thanks -- [here is a php example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) to get data from database...