# Error: Row given with size different than 5 (the number of columns in the table)

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

Having a hard time understanding one, presumably, basic thing. Could you please help me out?

I'm trying to create a Line Graph in Google Charts. For some reason it does not let me use NULL values.

First i fetch data via PHP from Postgres:

```
$rows = pg_fetch_all($fetch);
```

Then i try to plot the chart:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

      function drawBasic() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'X');
            data.addColumn('number', 'PD1');
            data.addColumn('number', 'CD1');
            data.addColumn('number', 'PD2');
            data.addColumn('number', 'CD2');

            data.addRows([<?php
            $result = '';
            foreach($rows as $data) {
              $result .= "['{$data['m']}', {$data['PD1']}, {$data['CD1']}, {$data['PD2']}, {$data['CD2']}],";
            }
            $result = rtrim($result,',');
            echo $result;
            ?>])

            var options = {
              hAxis: {
                title: 'T'
              },
              vAxis: {
                title: 'C'
              },
              interpolateNulls: true,
              width: 900,
              height: 500,
              title: 'Blahblah'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This attempt results in the following error:

```
jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:97 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row given with size different than 5 (the number of columns in the table).
  at gvjs_P.gvjs_.fZ (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:97)
  at gvjs_P.gvjs_.Op (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:98)
  at drawBasic (view_charts.php:18)
```

This happens when one of the values in my array is missing, for example:

```
data.addRows([['00:00', 85, 88, 6, 10],['00:01', 78, 86, 4, 9],['00:02', 110, 64, 8, 8],['00:03', 105, 82, , 4]])
```

If i change the query to select data where all values are present then the chart is shown without any issues. I thought that it's fine to pass null values, so some parts of the chart would have blank spots? Changing the NULL values to 0 is not an option as the result will be misleading.

Maybe the NULLS should be passed from PHP to JS in some kind of specific way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be a silly suggestion, but can you try using 0 where the element is null? If you have no control over the data, you can loop thru it and manually assign = 0 where NULL

Comment: Better create the final data array in PHP and then use `json_encode()` to convert it to JavaScript.

Comment: In Line chart, the code usually doesn't break upon receiving empty value. It simply skips that value. I used same code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6tmsemm/). It works fine. Also you're using `interpolateNulls` which takes care of this issue. Strange you're still facing it.

Comment: Currently you're triggering the php code inside the google chart (which is fine) but I would recommend you to execute that code before generating the chart and then pushing just the values.

Comment: the error is raised when the missing value is last in the array, need to use `json_encode` as already mentioned -- recommend not mixing php and javascript, use ajax to get data from php, similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)...

Comment: Thanks everyone, i've changed as you suggested, but after generating tha array and pushing the value via json_encode i am now receiving the following error: jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:97 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.

Comment: @WhiteHat does it mean that the last value of the array cannot be blank?

Comment: that's correct...