# Dynamic creation of multi series Google line chart with differing datetime series

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I have an undetermined number of data sets in a JSON feed. This means that I am never sure how many are coming back, it could be 1, 12 or 30, it's an unknown. The series are made up of a date and a value. I want to be able to draw a line chart with the multiple datasets. The datasets have different dates and times as well, to make things more complicated. I have the following code so far, that seems to create the `google.visualization.DataTable()` multiple times on the fly.

```
 success: function (d) {               
                var parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);
                $.each(parsedData, function (key, value) {                   
                    var dName = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 
                    dName.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                    dName.addColumn('number', 'Data');
                    var result = $.parseJSON(value);  
                    $.each(result, function (k, v) {                            
                        dName.addRow([new Date(v.ReadingDate), Number(v.ReadingValue)]);
                    });

                    console.log(dName);
                });   
            },....
```

I have checked that the data has arrays and values in it through the console. I am aware that I need to use the `google.visualization.data.join` method, but as I have an unknown number of data sets, I am not too sure how to create the join.

I have been able to do this with fixed numbers of datasets, but I am flummoxed as to how to join the data, I am not sure if it is even possible with Google Charts as it seems to be prescriptive.

From my research I need to be able to manipulate the following to join the different data series:

```
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(joinedData, {
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        interpolateNulls: true
    });
```

Here is a small sample of the JSON feed:

```
[{"LoggerId":"1000651443","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:03, "ReadingValue":"12.6", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"},
{"LoggerId":"1000651447","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:04:03, "ReadingValue":"12.7", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"}],
[{"LoggerId":"1000651444","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:05, "ReadingValue":"12.9", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"},
 {"LoggerId":"1000651445","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:07, "ReadingValue":"14.9", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"}],
[{"LoggerId":"1000651446","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:17, "ReadingValue":"13.6", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"},
 {"LoggerId":"1000651446","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:04:17, "ReadingValue":"43.6", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"}]
```

In summary, I want to be able to draw a multi-line chart with an unknown number of datasets, which have differing `datetimes`.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although a join would work, in this case, it isn't needed.

you can simply add a new column to the data table for each new json feed.

use the `setValue` method to apply the values, rather than `addRow`.

see following working snippet...

```js
 var section = $('#LocationNameDdl :selected').val();
    var uid = '@guid';
    var from = $('#dateFrom').val();
    var to = $('#dateTo').val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ProjectCharts/GetChartDataBySection',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        data: { section: section, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (d) {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                packages: ['corechart']
            }).then(function () {
                parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);
                var dName = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dName.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                $.each(parsedData, function (key, value) {
                    var colIndex = dName.addColumn('number', 'Data' + key);
                    var result = $.parseJSON(value);                    
                    $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                        var rowIndex = dName.addRow();
                        dName.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(v.ReadingDate));
                        dName.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, Number(v.ReadingValue));
                    });
                });

                var options = multiLineChartOptions();
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(dName, options);
            });

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: That works perfectly, I updated very little, I have added the final working version into your answer. Thanx!!!

Comment: One quesiton I do have, is that one of the charts has 30 devices in it with 8030 rows each 4 key values. The charts is taking an age to load and the browser fails doing it clinet side (runs out of memory). Is there a method to do the whole thing server side by any chance?

Comment: you wouldn't be able to build the chart server side, but you could try building the json in [this format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), which would allow you to create the data table directly, without any manipulation.

Comment: Kind of like building a string of strings of code and data and just send the whole thing over?

Comment: not sure what you're using on the server, but you should be able to build an array object then encode it as json -- [here is a php example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) of building the google json on the server

Comment: I'm using C# (netcore), but I see what you mean. As you can see I am doing all of the processing in the browser.