# JQuery loop slowing Google Chart performance

Tags: c#, json, charts, google-visualization, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a google chart, that generally is very slow (over 5 minutes) and sometimes just crashes depending on the number of series I need to show. If I have one series it takes around 10 seconds, but if I add say 20 series, it will take several minutes any more than that and the browser dies.

Each series has around 8,000 rows from the JSON. I have checked and tested the code and the loop in the chart code is killing it.

My chart code is as follows:

```
 function drawMultiLineChart() {    
        var section = $('#LocationNameDdl :selected').val();
        var uid = '@guid';
        var from = $('#dateFrom').val();
        var to = $('#dateTo').val();
        var parsedData = "";
        var dName = "";
        var colIndex = "";
        var result = "";
        var rowIndex = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ProjectCharts/GetChartDataBySection',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            data: { section: section, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (d) {
                google.charts.load('current', {
                    packages: ['corechart']
                }).then(function () {
                    parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);
                    dName = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    dName.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                    $.each(parsedData, function (key, value) {
                        colIndex = dName.addColumn('number', 'Serial: ' + key);
                        result = $.parseJSON(value);
                        $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                            rowIndex = dName.addRow();
                            dName.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(v.ReadingDate));
                            dName.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, Number(v.ReadingValue));
                        });
                    });

                    var options = multiLineChartOptions();
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                    chart.draw(dName, options);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    };
```

I call the JSON from the following code, this is fine and performs very quickly:

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetJsonChartData(string serial, string uid, string from, string to)
        {
            var dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(from).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            var dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(to).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            var g = new GetChartData(_configuration);
            List<ChartDataModel> items = await Task.Run(() => g.GetChartDataFromSqlServer(serial, uid, dateFrom, dateTo));           
            return  Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented));
        }
```

The JSON:

```
[{"LoggerId":"1000651443","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:03, "ReadingValue":"12.6", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"},
{"LoggerId":"1000651447","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:04:03, "ReadingValue":"12.7", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"}]

[{"LoggerId":"1000651444","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:05, "ReadingValue":"12.9", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"},
 {"LoggerId":"1000651445","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:07, "ReadingValue":"14.9", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"}]

[{"LoggerId":"1000651446","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:03:17, "ReadingValue":"13.6", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"},
 {"LoggerId":"1000651446","ReadingDate":"2018-12-05 00:04:17, "ReadingValue":"43.6", "Tooltip":"Someinfo"}]
```

How can I improve not only the performance but the load time? 
Should I be using a different charting tool?
Can I process the data server side that will allow for increased performance?

Comment: if you generate the json in the format found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), you will be able to create the data table directly, without any manipulation on the client, this will increase performance astronomically...

Comment: Thanks for this...I noticed there were a couple of wrappers out there for this (not for netcore), but can I just use a string builder to create the output.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with c# / netcore, a string builder would probably work, but you should be able to create the same json structure, then serialize it. for what its worth, here is a [php example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)...