# Is it possible to load multiple google charts on a single page with user clicks

Tags: php, html, google-visualization

I know its possible to have multiple charts side by side. But I have a line graph which uses a php/mysql query to pull data for the past 7 days and load it into the line chart. I want to have several options on the page like "WEEKLY", "QUARTERLY", "YEARLY" etc. When the user clicks a link it will trigger the appropriate query to run and load the new chart.

Can this be done all on one page or would I have to make a new page for each option? Mkaing a new page seems a bit greasy, would prefer it on one page. Could someone share the logic to set this up if its possible. I already have all the queries prepared and the charts work. Its just a matter for setting up the structure.

Comment: have the php on a separate page from the html & javascript, then pull the data from php using ajax, and the above will be possible. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)...

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a HTML form, not for time, but the series, but it'll do the same for you:

```
   <form action="" id="mainForm" name="metric" method="post">
        <select project="Metric" id="MetricList" name="MetricList" >
            <option value = "1"<?php echo (1 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Satisfaction</option>
            <option value = "2"<?php echo (2 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Recommendation</option>
            <option value = "3"<?php echo (3 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Missed Purchase Opportunity</option>
            <option value = "4"<?php echo (4 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Price</option>
            <option value = "5"<?php echo (5 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Range</option>
            <option value = "6"<?php echo (6 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Customer Serivce</option>
            <option value = "7"<?php echo (7 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Store Atmosphere</option>
            <option value = "8"<?php echo (8 == $submittedValue)?" SELECTED":""?>>Fresh Food</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

So that form is in my HTML, near the top of the page (but you can place wherever makes sense to you).

Near the top of my code I pick-up `$_POST["MetricList"]` and populate `$submittedValue`, this keeps the form displaying the selected value on refresh and lets me set up an `if` statement to select the SQL query to run that populates the google chart:

```
if (isset($_POST["MetricList"])) {
   $submittedValue = $_POST["MetricList"];
} else {
    $submittedValue = 1;
}
```

The `else = 1` is basically to handle first page load, to ensure we get what will be displayed first in the from populated in the chart, so, after that's set I can do an `if` statement on it:

```
if($submittedValue == 1){
//satisfaction
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $string .= ", FORMAT(AVG(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN q1 ELSE NULL END),1) AS '" . $row['NAME'] . "', CONCAT('\'" . $row['NAME'] . "|Score: ',FORMAT(AVG(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN q1 ELSE NULL END),1),'|Base: ',SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'\'') AS '" . $row['NAME'] . "_BASE'";
        $cstores .= "dataTable.addColumn('number', '" . $row['NAME'] . "'); dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});";
    }
}
//recommendation
elseif($submittedValue == 2){
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $string .= ", FORMAT(AVG(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN q2 ELSE NULL END),1) AS '" . $row['NAME'] . "', CONCAT('\'" . $row['NAME'] . "|Score: ',FORMAT(AVG(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN q2 ELSE NULL END),1),'|Base: ',SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'\'') AS '" . $row['NAME'] . "_BASE'";
        $cstores .= "dataTable.addColumn('number', '" . $row['NAME'] . "'); dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});";
    }
}
//mpo
elseif($submittedValue == 3){
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $string .= ", CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  '" . $row['NAME'] . "', CONCAT('\'" . $row['NAME'] . "|Percent: ',CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)),'%|Base: ',SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'\'') AS '" . $row['NAME'] . "_BASE'";
        $cstores .= "dataTable.addColumn('number', '" . $row['NAME'] . "'); dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});";
    }
}
```

etc... (don't worry about the `$row['NUM']` and `$row['NAME']`, that's just to build an added filter I have on stores that filter the selection too - multi filters!)

Then I pop that SQL snippet into my query:

```
<!--https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

function drawChart1() {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Month');
    //loop from above for store and store base
    <?php echo($cstores); ?>
    dataTable.addRows([

    <?php 

        $sql = "SELECT
                QUOTE(DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y')) AS 'Month'
                ". $string ."
            FROM data 
            WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
            ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        foreach( $query as $key => $array ) {
            echo("[");
            foreach( $array as $attribute => $value ) {
                echo str_replace("|","\\n",$value) . ","; //couldn't put \\n in the SQL above as it rendered in the output and broke it, so replacing the | here with \\n so it renders properly in the chart
            }
            echo("],");
        }
    ?> 

    ]);

   var options = {
      title: '',
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 10,
        <?php if($submittedValue == 3){ // adjust chart scale and axis if MPO
            echo("format: '#\'%\'',");
            echo("title: 'Percent',");
        }
        else{
            echo("title: 'Score 0-10'");
        }
        ?>
        },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        },
      pointSize: 10,
      pointShape: 'diamond'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

My chart has some added complication as I have HTML tooltips to push more data in (needed to show base and value for each item) but you should get the idea from here.