# How to make live update line chart from mysql database using chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I have a javascript file containing the chart.js code to draw a line chart. i succesfully connect the chart with MySql database and it was successful to display the chart on my index.php.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
?>

<?php 
  $koneksi    = mysqli_connect("my username, password, db name here");
  $created_at = mysqli_query($koneksi, 'SELECT created_at FROM (SELECT * FROM modul1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) Var1 ORDER BY id ASC');
  $sensor1 = mysqli_query($koneksi, 'SELECT sensor1 FROM (SELECT * FROM modul1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) Var1 ORDER BY id ASC');
?>

// Area Chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("GrafikRTU");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($created_at)) { echo '"' . $p['created_at'] . '",';}?>],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Earnings",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointRadius: 3,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($sensor1)) { echo '"' . $p['sensor1'] . '",';}?>],
  }],
  },
   options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 25,
        top: 25,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          padding: 10,
          // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '$' + number_format(value);
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [2],
          zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      titleMarginBottom: 10,
      titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
      titleFontSize: 14,
      borderColor: '#dddfeb',
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
      caretPadding: 10,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
          var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
          return datasetLabel + ': $' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But when MySql database collected new data, my chart was unable to display the updated data and i have to reload my index.php to display it. it is possible to have a live updated line chart with chart.js library without reload my index.php?

sorry for bad programming because i still study about php javascript programming for a short time.

Thankyou in Advance!

Comment: you'll want to separate the html / js and php pages into separate files. then use ajax from js to call the php page in order to get the data and update the chart.

Comment: Hi, i appreciate your suggestion, do you have any references on the web to use ajax call in order to do that, thanks!

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) is an example...