# How can I convert this JSON chart to real-time dynamic chart?

Tags: php, html, json, charts, google-visualization

This is the data that is in the database but I've only copy them so this is currently a static one and I can't convert this one into a real-time dynamic json chart.

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>

      let temp = 25; // testdata
      const gaugeArr = [
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Temperature', temp],
        ['pH', 7.2],
        ['DO', 60],
        ['Turbidity ', 10]
      ]; // testdata
      
      const lineObj = {"cols":[{"label":"Date Time","type":"datetime"},{"label":"Water Level (ft)","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628486400000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628485800000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628485200000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628484600000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628484000000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628483400000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628388000000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628302200000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628216400000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628130600000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1628044800000)"},{"v":"30.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627959000000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627873200000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627787400000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627701600000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627615800000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627530000000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627444200000)"},{"v":"30.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627358400000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627272600000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627186800000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627104600000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1627018800000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626933000000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626847200000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626761400000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626675600000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626589800000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626504000000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626418200000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626332400000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626246600000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626160800000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1626075000000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625989200000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625903400000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625817600000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625731800000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625646000000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625560200000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625474400000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625388600000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625302800000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625217000000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625131200000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1625045400000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624959600000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624873800000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624788000000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624702200000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624616400000)"},{"v":"30.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624530600000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624444800000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624359000000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624273200000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624187400000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624101600000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1624015800000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623930000000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623844200000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623758400000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623672600000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623586800000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623501000000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623415200000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623329400000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623243600000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623157800000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1623072000000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622986200000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622900400000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622814600000)"},{"v":"30.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622728800000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622643000000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622557200000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622471400000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622385600000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622299800000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622214000000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622128200000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1622042400000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621956600000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621870800000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621785000000)"},{"v":"30.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621612800000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621527000000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621441200000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621355400000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621269600000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621183800000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621098000000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1621012200000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620926400000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620840600000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620754800000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620669000000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620583200000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620497400000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620411600000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620325800000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620240000000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620154200000)"},{"v":"36.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1620068400000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619982600000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619896800000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619811000000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619725200000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619639400000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619553600000)"},{"v":"37.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619467800000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619382000000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619296200000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619210400000)"},{"v":"25.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619124600000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1619038800000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618953000000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618867200000)"},{"v":"38.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618781400000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618695600000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618609800000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618524000000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618438200000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618352400000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618266600000)"},{"v":"31.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618180800000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618095000000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1618009200000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617923400000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617837600000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617751800000)"},{"v":"28.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617666000000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617580200000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617494400000)"},{"v":"40.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617408600000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617322800000)"},{"v":"32.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617237000000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617151200000)"},{"v":"29.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1617065400000)"},{"v":"35.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1616979600000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1616893800000)"},{"v":"26.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1616808000000)"},{"v":"33.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1616722200000)"},{"v":"27.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1616636400000)"},{"v":"39.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(1616550600000)"},{"v":"34.00"}]}]}
      

      let lineChart, gauge;
  
      const drawChart = () => {
        if (!lineChart) lineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div')); // only do this once
        if (!gauge) gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div')); // only do this once
        var gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gaugeArr);
        var lineData = new google.visualization.DataTable(lineObj);
        lineChart.draw(lineData, lineOptions);
        gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
      }

      const getData = () => {


        drawChart(); 
        gaugeArr[1][1] = ++temp
        setTimeout(getData, 5000); 
      };
      window.addEventListener("load", () => { // when page loads
        google.charts.load('current', {
          'packages': ['gauge','corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData); // start
      })



const lineOptions = {
          title: "Sensors Data",
          legend: {
            position: "bottom"
          },
          chartArea: {
            width: "80%",
            height: "70%"
          }
        };
const gaugeOptions  = {
                width: 500,
                height: 200,
                minorTicks: 5,
              };
      


    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="linechart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px,; margin-top:30px"></div>
      <div id="gauge_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px,; margin-top:30px"></div>
  </body>
```

This is the php syntax that I use to get the data from the database and a working one but only if they are the only json chart in that page but what I want to happen is to display them both in one page and also I don't know how can I integrate this in a two combined json table to make them dynamic.

```
<?php    
// For line chart
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'adminpanel');
$sql = 'SELECT temperature, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(" ", sensor_date , sensor_time)) AS datetime
FROM tbl_waterquality ORDER BY sensor_date DESC, sensor_time DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
  array(
    'label' => 'Date Time',
    'type' => 'datetime'
  ),
  array(
    'label' => 'Water Level (ft)',
    'type' => 'number'
  ),
);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $sub_array = array();
  $datetime = explode(".", $row["datetime"]);
  $sub_array[] = array(
    "v" => 'Date(' . $datetime[0] . '000)'
  );
  $sub_array[] = array(
    "v" => $row["temperature"]
  );
  $rows[] = array(
    "c" => $sub_array
  );
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>

//For Gauge chart
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'adminpanel');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_waterquality ORDER BY id DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // assuming ONE result

$temperature = $row["temperature"];
$pH = $row["pH"];
$DO = $row["DO"];
$turbidity = $row["Turbidity"];

echo <<<EOT
[
["Label", "Value"],
["Temperature", $temperature],
["pH", $pH ],
["DO", $DO ],
["Turbidity", $turbidity ]
]
EOT
?>
```

Comment: separate the php into two pages, one for each dataset. then use ajax from javascript to call each php page, get the data, and draw the charts. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771) is an example...

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you very much for your help, I'll try it hope you reply when I'm getting stuck at some part.

Comment: @WhiteHat Hello can you help me how can I used this syntax in the link that you gave because I have two different charts that I want to display and I don't know how can I call those two chart that I have. Thank you.