# How to update a Google Chart periodically?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Currently, I'm trying to update the value of my Google Line Chart. My aim is to update it periodically, so that I can obtain the result of a dynamic chart. Right now I need to refresh the whole page, but this is not a good solution.

I tried with `setTimeout()` function, but recalling the function `drawChart()` doesn't seem to be working. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
  {
            // The intervals data as narrow lines (useful for showing raw source data)
    var options = {
        title: 'Valores de LDR1',
        vAxis: { ticks: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]},
        curveType: 'function',
        lineWidth: 4,
        legend: 'none'
    }
    
    
    var ldr1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ldr1'));
    var ldr2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ldr2'));
    var ldr3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ldr3'));
    var ldr4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ldr4'));

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php prueba('ldr1') ?>);
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php prueba('ldr2') ?>);
    var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php prueba('ldr3') ?>);
    var data4 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php prueba('ldr4') ?>);
        
    ldr1.draw(data, options);       
    options["title"] = "Valores de LDR2";               
    ldr2.draw(data2, options);
    options["title"] = "Valores de LDR3";               
    ldr3.draw(data3, options);
    options["title"] = "Valores de LDR4";               
    ldr4.draw(data4, options);
    updateChart();
    
    setTimeout(drawChart, 1000);
 }
```

The php code get values from the database, so as I see it, I only have to repeat the code of the function `drawChart()`, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: the php code only runs once, on the server, when the page is requested. the result is written to the page, so calling the function multiple times will produce the same result. recommend separating pages, php on one page, html / javascript on another. then use ajax to request data from php page. here is an example --> [Redraw google chart based on user input via AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947898/redraw-google-chart-based-on-user-input-via-ajax-request/38955110#38955110)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot! However, it's not working still, but now it's only the problem of conversion, I think. PHP script returns string (values as "[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]") and I cannot convert it to DataTable to draw them on a chart. If I take `responseText`, I get a repeating error (kind of success), but when I try to convert the data (`google.visualization.DataTable`) it gets stucked and nothing happens.

Comment: if you could edit the question with the latest code, I'll take a look